# Parse changing XML using XStream

Tags: java, parsing, xml-parsing, xstream

I am receiving an XML response from a server. But response is changing according to my request. I want to parse XML response using XStream Parser. While converting from XML to POJOs , I am getting exceptions of "unrecognized fields".
I only want some fields during conversion and ignore the rest. For example:
My Pojo class is:

```
    @XStreamAlias("Book")
    class Book{
        @XStreamAlias("author")
        private String author;

        @XStreamAlias("title")
        private String title;

        //getters and setters
   }
```

If my response is :

```
<book>
  <author>ABC</author>
  <title>XYZ</title>
</book>
```

Conversion works fine. But if my response is:

```
<book>
  <author>ABC</author>
  <title>XYZ</title>
  <pages>50</pages>
</book>
```

I am getting exceptions during conversion. How can I avoid such exceptions for unwanted fields? Is there any way to tell XStream to avoid any other field which is not mentioned in POJO?

Comment: Hi, if the answer satisfy you requirements - then please mark it as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set XStream to ignore unknown elements: `xStream.ignoreUnknownElements()`

```
@XStreamAlias("Book")
class Book {

    @XStreamAlias("author")
    String author;

    @XStreamAlias("title")
    String title;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "<Book>"
                + "<author>ABC</author>"
                + "<title>XYZ</title>"
                + "<pages>50</pages>"
                + "</Book>";

        XStream xStream = new XStream();
        xStream.ignoreUnknownElements();
        xStream.processAnnotations(Book.class);

        Book book = (Book) xStream.fromXML(input);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How do you instanciate XStream?

You could try with `omitField()` if you know the names of the fields to omit, or even better, read this resource.
http://rafaelsteil.com/omit-unexpected-xml-elements-with-xstream/